# Unable to validate your application error

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been trying to upload the new version of build on test flight but I always get error like:

> Unable to validate your application. The application you have selected does not exist.

Comment: My Xcode version was 6.3. I was facing this issue. Finally I updated Xcode to 7.1, Was able to upload to itunesconnect successfully.

Comment: @ Vinoy Alexander I have updated xcode to 7.1 and use his application loader for submit app. but it gives error "Missing beta entitlements". i created the .ipa file from xcode 6.4 version.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Application Loader**. It works! Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWCDks75hg8) of how to do this and [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html) for reference.

Comment: I have already used Application Loader for submission and it successfully submitted. But in test flight it got error like "Missing beta entitlements". And no use for this version.

Comment: I see. Could you please try adding `beta-reports-active ` key in your `Entitlements.plist`. Set it to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your app is not configured on iTunesConnect. Make sure that you are using the correct bundle identifier. The bundle ID on iTunesConnect and in Xcode project should be same. Otherwise export the IPA and upload it using **Application Loader**.

Comment: I have already submitted many versions. but i got this issue last 2 days.

Comment: @Hitendra: It seems to an ongoing problem with Apple.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/23606